# Ведомство = министерство?

Tags: синонимы, названия

Всегда ли ***ведомство*** можно употребить как синоним ***министерства***?

Вообще, насколько синонимичны эти понятия?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ведомство** - не синоним министерства, а *более широкое понятие*. На министерство (как частный случай) этим словом ссылаются неформально (напр. "в ведомстве такого-то министра"), для разнообразия речевых оборотов. Под тем, что именуется **ведомствами**, чаще всего подразумевают *менее крупные*, чем министерство, органы управления - отсюда выражение "министерства и ведомства" (ср. "собрано столько-то картофеля и овощей"). Ведомства далеко не всегда входят в состав какого-либо министерства.

Answer (score 0):

Это не синонимичные понятия. Если сто лет тому в обиходе их нередко употребляли как синонимы, то уже в СССР под министерством и ведомством понимали совершенно разные органы/структуры. Основное отличие в том, что ведомство не обладает самостоятельной властью и подчинено обычно какому-то вышестоящему органу (тому же министерству, например).

Для примера, Вы можете зайти на [правительственный сайт](http://government.ru/ministries/) с перечнем министерств и ведомств. Все те службы и агентства, которые подчинены указанным министерствам, и называются ведомствами. Но чёткого определения понятия "ведомство" в законодательстве РФ нет. Вот цитата из Википедии (статья [Ведомство](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)):

> В законодательстве Российской Федерации термин «ведомство» четко не определен.